# FlatList's onEndReached is being called without reaching end of the list

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

As soon as list is rendered `onEndReached` is being called without even scrolling the list. Initially 40 records are rendering and according to my tab device height I am able to see 17 records at a time. That means still there are 23 records to scroll.

I have followed this Git [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12827). But that didn't work for me.

Note: this problem is occurring only in iOS Tablet. In android Mobile, Tablet and in iOS mobile working fine.

Could anybody let me know the solution to prevent this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: trying playing with onEndReachedThreshold

Comment: @Victor I tried to give the values from 0 to 1, But no result.